# Indefinite integral involving exponential and arbitrary function

Tags: indefinite-integrals

If I have for any piecewise continuous function $f$
$$
F(x) = \int f(x)\ dx
$$
is it possible to calculate
$$
\int f(ax+b)\ e^{cx}\ dx
$$
If $f$ is $sin$ then a computer algebra system gives me
$$
(e^{cx}\ (sin(ax + b) - a\ cos(ax + b)))/(a^2 + c^2)
$$
However for a general $f$ the system says that there is no solution using standard mathematical functions.

I am not necessarily looking for an actual formula for it and argument for its existence would suffice (with not too onerous preconditions if required).

Comment: We know that $\int \frac{1}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \log x$ (up to an additive constant), but it is proved that $\int \frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x$ has no elementary antiderivative. Even $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ will give you yet another integral without elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at your examples has made me realise I also have that $f$ is piecewise continuous.